# Using count(array) causes Error to be thrown

Tags: php

I've got this line in code in module CMap.php which is part of the yii framework which should count the number of elements in array `_d`.

```
return count($this->_d);
```

Howver, if `_d` is an `array[0]` it raises the error:

> Trying to obtain property of non object

Using PHP v5.3.3 (x86) which is the same version as installed on our webserver.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

EDIT:
Changed the code to this:

```
try {
  return null;

  if ($this->_d==null)
    return null;
  else {
    if(isset($this->_d[$key]))
      return $this->_d[$key];
    else
      return null;
    }
  }
catch (Exception $e) {
  return null;
}
```

And it still throws an errors on the first `return null;` line without entering the `catch()` block.

Comment: can you post the output of _d??

Comment: _d is an empty array. In the watch window it shows as array[0]

Comment: to clarify, its type is array[0], value is showing as blank...

Comment: Also, if I change the test to "if ($this->_d==NULL)" I also get the same error... But in the watch window that formula has a value of 1.

Comment: The statement `return null;` doesn't have any reason to trigger an error. I suspect the calling code attempts to use this `null` as an object.

Comment: What is the **exact** wording of the error message, including the backtrace? Trying to simplify things you don't understand makes it harder for other people to explain them to you; only mask out details which would give away security or trade secrets.

Comment: To the code from your edit, none of the code below your `return null` is actually executed. So if you then try to do `$this->_d` on a `NULL` value it's normal it will throw an error.

Not related to the issue, but you should also take a look at the PHP coding standards, quite some code smells in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down the error message:

> Trying to obtain property

A "property" is a field of some object, and "property access" is what you do with the `->` operator. In your case, `$this->_d`.

> of non object

In the expression `$this->_d`, we would say "`_d` is a property of `$this`". So "of a non-object" means the thing on the *left* of the `->` operator is not an object.

So *assuming the code you've posted is accurate*, and not anonymized to the point where it's hiding the real error, your problem is that `$this` is not an object in that part of the code.

Note that this contradicts your claim that `$this->_d` is an empty array, because if `$this` is not an object, then `$this->_d` *does not exist*. So I strongly suspect that you're looking in the wrong place, or you've tried to simplify the description but missed out crucial details.

Comment: I can assure you that $this does exist - a tooltip shows lots of properties.

Comment: I think that the YII framework is hiding a lot 'stuff' because the stack trace seems to have a lot of steps missing between the error being raised and the alleged previous step... Maybe it has thrown an error in its internal code? This code doesn't display itself as I single-step the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to close this thread off now.

The code posted in my OP wasn't buggy, and wasn't causing the error.

Complete red herring. What is happening is that the code running *after this method* (the code which calls this method) is throwing the error, but for some reason that code doesn't show up in my debugger. I can't step through it.

The first I see of any debugging is when a breakpoint in the ErrorHandler gets hit.

I'll raise a separate Question on how/why the YII framework is doing that.

Thanks for you comments guys.

Comment: **Sometime the best debugger is you !!!** Try `echo $your_var , "or some text";` and `print_r($your_array);` or `print_r($your_object);` Terminate your script with `die("some optional message");` right after;
It's what I do when I want to see exactly what appens.

Comment: Nah, the best debugger is xdebug :) but I get what you mean, `var_dump()` is also pretty useful!